# What is useLocalSessionState used for?

Tags: mysql, sql, autocommit

I had an issue with MySQL db where the setAutocommit were being logged many times even though there was no autocommit mode change. For example, if I call setautocommit(false) 5 times, I see 5 queries in the query log saying set autommit=0;

This is usually not supposed to happen as the autocommit mode hasnt changed. The query should be sent only when I am changing the autocommit mode i.e. say 1 to 0.

When I did some looking in the MySQL connection class implementation, I figured that they check useLocalSessionState value to decide whether they want to execute the query or not?

```
 if ((getUseLocalSessionState()) && (this.autoCommit == autoCommitFlag)) {
            needsSetOnServer = false;
          }
```

So, even though this.autocommit & autocommit flag are same, needsSetOnServer is NOT set to false becuase useLocalSessionState is defaulted to false.

Once I add useLocalSessionState = true in my connection URL, I dont see the unnecessary query logs.

So, my questions are :

1. What is the significance of useLocalSessionState ? Why is it used generally?
2. Is it safe to set useLocalSessionState = true?

PS : I see that SQL Server handles this kind of a scenario without any such dependencies i.e. (Code snippet from SQLServerConnection

```
if (paramBoolean == this.databaseAutoCommitMode) {
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Referring to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html:

> Should the driver refer to the internal values of autocommit and transaction isolation that are set by Connection.setAutoCommit() and Connection.setTransactionIsolation() and transaction state as maintained by the protocol, rather than querying the database or blindly sending commands to the database for commit() or rollback() method calls?

My interpretation of this (after looking to the code of the MySQL JDBC driver) is that instead of issuing e.g. a `SELECT @@session.tx_read_only`, it checks the `readOnly` property of the connection class:

**ConnectionImpl.java** (MySQL JDBC connecotr 5.1.31):

```
public boolean isReadOnly() throws SQLException {
    return this.isReadOnly(true);
}

public boolean isReadOnly(boolean useSessionStatus) throws SQLException {
    if(useSessionStatus && /*...*/ && !this.getUseLocalSessionState()) {
        //...

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select @@session.tx_read_only");

        //...
    } else {
        return this.readOnly;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, it only issues a SQL command for setting the read only state if useLocalSessionState is false:

```
public void setReadOnlyInternal(boolean readOnlyFlag) throws SQLException {
    if((/*...*/ !this.getUseLocalSessionState()) {
        this.execSQL((StatementImpl)null, "set session transaction " + (readOnlyFlag?"read only":"read write"), -1, (Buffer)null, 1003, 1007, false, this.database, (Field[])null, false);
    }

    this.readOnly = readOnlyFlag;
}
```

I assume that the same applies for the auto-commit and transaction isolation level properties.